# Search the database using 4 different select boxes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I have a rather complex "WHERE" statement to create. I have searched many sites to find answers and yet my page still shows nothing.

Business requirement: Use 4 different drop downs to get results from the database either by selecting one, all, or any combination of all four.

Here is the php code for the file searchInstructors.php:

```
         <?php
        $dsn = 'mysql: host=localhost; dbname=name';
        $user = 'user';
        $password = 'pass';
        try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

         if(isset($_GET['semester'])){
            $semester = $_GET['semester'];  
        }else{
            $semester = "Not Selected";
        }
        if(isset($_GET['year'])){
            $year = $_GET['year'];  
        }else{
            $year = "Not Selected";
        }
        if(isset($_GET['coursePrefix'])){
            $coursePrefix = $_GET['coursePrefix'];  
        }else{
            $coursePrefix = "Not Selected";
        }
        if(isset($_GET['courseNumber'])){
            $courseNumber = $_GET['courseNumber'];  
        }else{
            $courseNumber = "Not Selected";
        }

        echo "<table class='tg' width='100%'>";
        echo "<tr>

                <th><strong>Course</strong></th>        
                <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Email/Phone</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Semester</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Institution</strong></th>
        </tr>";
        $sql="SELECT courses.coursePrefix  courses.courseNumber,   facultyContact.firstName, facultyContact.lastName, facultyContact.email, facultyContact.phone, facultyContact.institution, courses.semester, courses.year
        FROM courses
        LEFT JOIN facultyContact 
        ON courses.ID=facultyContact.ID
        WHERE (courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.year LIKE :year)
OR (courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix)
OR (courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber) 
OR (courses.year LIKE :year AND courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix)
OR (courses.year LIKE :year AND courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber)
OR (courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix AND courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber)
OR (courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.year LIKE :year AND courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix)
OR (courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.year LIKE :year AND courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber)
OR  (courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.year LIKE :year AND courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix AND courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber)
        ORDER BY facultyContact.lastName";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':semester', $semester, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':year', $year, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':coursePrefix', $coursePrefix, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':courseNumber', $courseNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $total = $stmt->rowCount();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {

           echo "<tr>
                <td>{$row->coursePrefix}<br /> {$row->courseNumber} </td>
                <td>{$row->firstName} {$row->lastName}</td>
                <td>{$row->email} <br />{$row->phone}</td>
                <td>{$row->semester} {$row->year} </td>
                <td>{$row->institution} </td>";
        }
        if (empty($total)) { 
            echo '<td colspan="5">No results found for your selection<br>' .
        '<strong>'. $semester . ' - ' . $year. ' - ' .  $coursePrefix. ' - ' .     $courseNumber . '</strong></td>'; 
        } else {
            echo implode($total);
        }

        $pdo = null;
        echo "</tr></table>";
           ?>
```

Here is the HTML code in search_form.php:

```
                <div class="search-wrapper">
         <form id="form2" method="get" action="searchInstructors.php"> 
            <p> 
            <label for="semester">Semester</label>
                <select name="semester" id="semester">
                  <option selected="selected" value="Not Selected">Select One</option>
                  <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
                  <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
                  <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
              </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="year">Year</label>
                <select name="year" id="year">
                  <option selected="selected" value="Not Selected">Select One</option>
                  <option value="2015">2015</option>
                  <option value="2014">2014</option>
                  <option value="2013">2013</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for="coursePrefix">Course Subject</label> 
             <select name="coursePrefix" id="coursePrefix">
               <option selected="selected" value="Not Selected">Select One</option>
               <option value="ACED">ACED</option>
               <option value="CRJU">CRJU</option>
               <option value="ENGL">ENGL</option>
               <option value="FREN">FREN</option>
               <option value="HADM">HADM</option>
               <option value="LEAS">LEAS</option>
               <option value="ORGL">ORGL</option>
               <option value="PLA">PLA</option>
               <option value="POLS">POLS</option>
               <option value="PSYC">PSYC</option>
               <option value="SOCI">SOCI</option>
               <option value="SPAN">SPAN</option>
             </select>
        </p>
        <p>

    <label for="courseNumber">Course Number</label> 
     <select name="courseNumber" id="courseNumber">
       <option selected="selected" value="Not Selected">Select One</option>
       <option value="1100">1100</option>
       <option value="1101">1101</option>
       <option value="1102">1102</option>
       <option value="2000">2000</option>
       <option value="2010">2010</option>
       <option value="2050">2050</option>
       <option value="2100">2100</option>
       <option value="2200">2200</option>
       <option value="2300">2300</option>
       <option value="2400">2400</option>
       <option value="2700">2700</option>
       <option value="3000">3000</option>
       <option value="3001">3001</option>
       <option value="3002">3002</option>
       <option value="3010">3010</option>
       <option value="3030">3030</option>
       <option value="3050">3050</option>
       <option value="3100">3100</option>
       <option value="3101">3101</option>
       <option value="3110">3110</option>
       <option value="3150">3150</option>
       <option value="3160">3160</option>
       <option value="3200">3200</option>
       <option value="3201">3201</option>
       <option value="3210">3210</option>
       <option value="3220">3220</option>
       <option value="3230">3230</option>
       <option value="3240">3240</option>
       <option value="3250">3250</option>
       <option value="3260">3260</option>
       <option value="3300">3300</option>
       <option value="3301">3301</option>
       <option value="3302">3302</option>
       <option value="3303">3303</option>
       <option value="3304">3304</option>
       <option value="3350">3350</option>
       <option value="3400">3400</option>
       <option value="3500">3500</option>
       <option value="3501">3501</option>
       <option value="3600">3600</option>
       <option value="3610">3610</option>
       <option value="3700">3700</option>
       <option value="3710">3710</option>
       <option value="3800">3800</option>
       <option value="3810">3810</option>
       <option value="4000">4000</option>
       <option value="4001">4001</option>
       <option value="4002">4002</option>
       <option value="4011">4011</option>
       <option value="4020">4020</option>
       <option value="4050">4050</option>
       <option value="4070">4070</option>
       <option value="4110">4110</option>
       <option value="4160">4160</option>
       <option value="4200">4200</option>
       <option value="4210">4210</option>
       <option value="4220">4220</option>
       <option value="4230">4230</option>
       <option value="4240">4240</option>
       <option value="4250">4250</option>
       <option value="4251">4251</option>
       <option value="4260">4260</option>
       <option value="4300">4300</option>
       <option value="4301">4301</option>
       <option value="4350">4350</option>
       <option value="4401">4401</option>
       <option value="4402">4402</option>
       <option value="4500">4500</option>
       <option value="4600">4600</option>
       <option value="4610">4610</option>
       <option value="4620">4620</option>
       <option value="4650">4650</option>
       <option value="4690">4690</option>
       <option value="4700">4700</option>
       <option value="4800">4800</option>
       <option value="4802">4802</option>
       <option value="4820">4820</option>
       <option value="4860">4860</option>
       <option value="4900">4900</option>
       <option value="4950">4950</option>
       <option value="4960">4960</option>
       <option value="4980">4980</option>
       <option value="4991">4991</option>
     </select>
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search" class="btn" />
 </form>
 </div>
```

This doesn't work. So I tried this:

```
 if(isset($_GET['semester'])){
 $semester = $_GET['semester'];
 $query="SELECT courses.coursePrefix, courses.courseNumber, facultyContact.firstName, facultyContact.lastName, facultyContact.email, facultyContact.phone, facultyContact.institution, courses.semester, courses.year
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN facultyContact 
ON courses.ID=facultyContact.ID
WHERE courses.semester LIKE :semester OR courses.year LIKE :year OR  courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix OR courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber
ORDER BY facultyContact.lastName";
 }else{
    $semester = "Not Selected";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['year'])){
     $year = $_GET['year'];
    $query="SELECT courses.coursePrefix, courses.courseNumber, facultyContact.firstName, facultyContact.lastName, facultyContact.email, facultyContact.phone, facultyContact.institution, courses.semester, courses.year
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN facultyContact 
ON courses.ID=facultyContact.ID
WHERE courses.semester LIKE :semester OR courses.year LIKE :year OR courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix OR courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber
ORDER BY facultyContact.lastName";
 }else{  
    $year = "Not Selected";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['coursePrefix'])){
     $coursePrefix = $_GET['coursePrefix'];
    $query="SELECT courses.coursePrefix, courses.courseNumber, facultyContact.firstName, facultyContact.lastName, facultyContact.email, facultyContact.phone, facultyContact.institution, courses.semester, courses.year
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN facultyContact 
ON courses.ID=facultyContact.ID
WHERE courses.semester LIKE :semester OR courses.year LIKE :year OR courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix OR courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber
ORDER BY facultyContact.lastName";
 }else{
   $coursePrefix = "Not Selected";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['courseNumber'])){
     $courseNumber = $_GET['courseNumber'];
    $query="SELECT courses.coursePrefix, courses.courseNumber, facultyContact.firstName, facultyContact.lastName, facultyContact.email, facultyContact.phone, facultyContact.institution, courses.semester, courses.year
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN facultyContact 
ON courses.ID=facultyContact.ID
WHERE courses.semester LIKE :semester OR courses.year LIKE :year OR courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix OR courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber
ORDER BY facultyContact.lastName";
 }else{  
   $courseNumber = "Not Selected";
 }
```

It didn't work either. I can make it work when the WHERE statement is all AND and all OR. It will work with two drop down and one or like this:

```
courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.year LIKE :year OR 
courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.coursePrefix LIKE :coursePrefix OR
courses.semester LIKE :semester AND courses.courseNumber LIKE :courseNumber
```

I had thought about creating views and just making each drop down pull the view,  but there are too many combinations and when new courses are added I will have to redo the views. 
Is it possible to create a WHERE statement or query that will take input from 4 drop downs in any combination?

Comment: you sure like `like` huh

Comment: why not put AND and OR dropdowns next to each dropdown so the user can decide whether to AND or OR

Comment: oh, I get the any combination thing now. Don't add the field to the WHERE clause if no value was selected...done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many more hours spent researching I have code that works. So this is for everyone else that has to do something complex.

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql: local host; dbname=dbName';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass;
try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
try{
    $query = "SELECT courses.coursePrefix, courses.courseNumber, facultyContact.firstName, facultyContact.lastName, facultyContact.email, facultyContact.phone, facultyContact.institution, courses.semester, courses.year
FROM courses 
LEFT JOIN facultyContact 
ON courses.ID=facultyContact.ID ";
$cond = array();
$params = array();

 if( isset($_GET['semester']) && !(empty($_GET['semester'])) ){  
    $cond[] = " courses.semester LIKE '". $_GET['semester']."'";
    $params[] = $semester;

}
if(isset($_GET['year']) && !(empty($_GET['year'])) ){  
    $cond[] = " courses.year LIKE '". $_GET['year']."'";
    $params[] = $year;
}
if(isset($_GET['coursePrefix']) && !(empty($_GET['coursePrefix'])) ){
    $cond[] = " courses.coursePrefix LIKE '". $_GET['coursePrefix']."'";
    $params[] = $coursePrefix;
}
if(isset($_GET['courseNumber']) && !(empty($_GET['courseNumber'])) ){
    $cond[] = " courses.courseNumber LIKE '". $_GET['courseNumber'] ."'";
    $params[] = $courseNumber;
}
if (count($cond)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
}
$query.= "ORDER BY facultyContact.lastName, facultyContact.firstName";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);

echo "<table class='tg' width='100%'>";
echo "<tr>

        <th><strong>Course</strong></th>        
        <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Email/Phone</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Semester</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Institution</strong></th>
</tr>";

$total = $stmt->rowCount();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

   echo "<tr>    
        <td>" . $row['coursePrefix'] . " ". $row['courseNumber'] . "</td>" .

        "<td>" . $row['firstName'] . " " . $row['lastName'] . "</td>" .

        "<td>" . $row['email']. "<br />" . $row['phone'] ."</td>" .

        "<td>" . $row['semester'] ." " . $row['year'] . "</td>" .

        "<td>" . $row['institution'] . "</td></tr>";
}
//user error message for no results
if (empty($total)) { 
    echo '<td colspan="5">No results found for your selection<br>' .
'<strong>'. $_GET['semester'] . ' - ' . $_GET['year']. ' - ' .  $_GET['coursePrefix'] . ' - ' . $_GET['courseNumber'] . '</strong></td>'; 
} else {
    echo implode($total);
}
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_messageALL = $e->getMessage();
    echo "DB error: " . $error_messageALL;  

    }

    $pdo = null;
    echo "</tr></table>";
       ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually creating SQL for every possible combination of semester, year, prefix, and number, let PHP build it dynamically.

Define all the variables that you'll want to use in your SQL.

```
$inputs = array(
    'semester'      => false,
    'year'          => false,
    'coursePrefix'  => false,
    'courseNumber'  => false
);
```

Check for the presence of your variables in the $_GET array.

```
foreach ( $inputs as $k => $v ) {
    if ( isset($_GET[$k]) ) {
        $inputs[$k] = $_GET[$k];
    }
}
```

Dynamically build the where clause in your SQL.  NOTE: my code is a starting point and doesn't do everything you need, such as bindings.  You'll have to do that yourself.

```
$sql = 'SELECT your_columns FROM courses LEFT JOIN your_joins ';
$where = array();
foreach ( $inputs as $k => $v ) {
    if ( $v !== false ) {
        $where[$k] = 'courses.'.$k.' = :'.$k;   
    }
}
if ( sizeof($where) > 0 ) {
    $sql .= 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);  
}
$sql .= ' ORDER BY some_columns';
```

Now play with a few URLs, e.g.

```
semester=Summer&year=2009&coursePrefix=PLA
semester=Summer&year=2009
semester=Summer
```

And note how the code doesn't know or care exactly which combination of parameters is given.

Once you work that out, adding the option to allow the user to specify and/or between parameters - or allowing them to select multiples (e.g. checkboxes) is super easy.

Comment: I can see bindings here, but no escaping or whitelisting of column names. Might be worth adding a note (or relying on mine!) to say that users of this code need to be careful about SQL injection here.

Comment: Columns are clearly defined in $inputs, and are not modified by any user submitted data.  I'd take it a step further though and create a more complex array that holds the data types used by the PDO bindings!

Comment: Ah, great - I didn't see this is whitelisted already! The `some_columns` bit is not implemented however, and I think anyone taking this as a starting point would still be well advised to be careful. Using `$_GET` safely can be a minefield.